# PHP 5.6 not working - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, apt, package-management

I had **PHP5.3** on my ubuntu and is now trying to install **PHP5.6** on it.

After purging the current version, This is what I've done first:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install php5.6

But there are no packages available in that name (checked php-5.6, php56 too, but no luck)

When trying the command

- apt-get install php5

, it installs PHP, but the older version (**5.3**)

It appears the packages are not getting fetched from the PPA or something.

Also, I've done an apt-get clean all, and redid the above steps, but still nothing.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Ubuntu [12.04 is EOL](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life). There will be no more security fixes for your system. Upgrade to a newer version that is still supported and it will be easier to install the newer version of PHP as well.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answers, your [Ubuntu 12.04 is out of support since April 2017](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) and the default repositories nor those of Ondrej Sury will work, as [he makes clear he doesn't support end of life releases, either of PHP or Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej):

> Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested
>   extensions are included. Only Supported Versions of PHP
>   (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases
>   (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for
>   end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

Ondraj repository supports php 5.6 for Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 17.10 and 18.04:

```
php5.6  5.6.36-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1   Ondřej Surý (2018-05-02)
php5.6  5.6.36-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   Ondřej Surý (2018-05-02)
php5.6  5.6.36-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1   Ondřej Surý (2018-05-02)
php5.6  5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1   Ondřej Surý (2018-05-02)
```

You should upgrade to *at least* ***Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty*** to use his repository and install php 5.6, or upgrade to a later Ubuntu version (16.04 or 18.04) and use php 7 or above.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache search php` will give you a list of packages which are related to PHP. You can find your PHP package over there.

Comment: done that. seems like there are no packages for the versions above 5.3. It's like the packages from that ppa is not getting fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Every Ubuntu main version comes with fixed PHP version.

- Your Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS has been [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) since April 28, 2017. It had PHP 5.3.
- Trusty (14.04 LTS) has PHP 5.5 (until EOL in April 2019). PHP 5.5 itself is not [supported](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php).
- Xenial (16.04 LTS) has PHP 7.0.
- Artful (17.10) has PHP 7.1.
- Bionic (18.04 LTS) has PHP 7.2.

If you need another version or multiple ([supported](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php)) versions of PHP, you can:

- Compile them by yourself.
- Add the Personal Package Archive (PPA) repository

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  and use [packages](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) maintained by Ondřej Surý, e.g.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install php7.2
  ```